# How do I register Firebird in .NET Core 5?

Tags: c#, .net-core, firebird, firebird-.net-provider

I am currently trying to port a .NET Framework application to .NET Core. We're using Firebird as a database. I updated the dependencies and most issues could be solved, but when compiling and starting the program I get the error:

> Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type
> 'FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory'. Make sure
> that the ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the
> application config.

The old app.config looked like this:

```xml
configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>

  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient"/>
      <add name="FirebirdClient Data Provider" invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Firebird" type="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

system.data is not available in .NET Core anymore and some of the dependencies have changed. So my new app.config looks like this:

```xml
<configuration>

    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
        <section name="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory" type="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient"/>
    </configSections>

    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="EntityFramework.Firebird.FbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework.Firebird" />
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" type="EntityFramework.Firebird.FbProviderServices, EntityFramework.Firebird"/>
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
```

I've tried different things, I've read the documentation and I made sure that the dependencies EntityFramework.Firebird, EntityFrameworkCore.Firebird and Firebird.Sql.FirebirdClient are there, which contain the classes references in my app.config. I am really at a loss as to what is missing and I am sure it is something obvious. So mabye anymore here knows what I can do to provide the factory.

Comment: Don't use .NET 5. It's already out of support. It was a single year "Current" release. The long term support version is .NET 6

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, consider asking on the [firebird-net-provider Google Group](https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-net-provider)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel this isn't a Firebird question. The OP is trying to configure a .NET Core application using a .NET Old config file which simply doesn't work any more. It's unclear whether EF 6 or EF Core is used, but EF Core doesn't require configuring provider factories nor does it use them

Comment: Is EF or EF Core used? How was the application migrated? `app.config` can still be used by adding a compatibility NuGet package to allow reading settings explicitly, but its contents won't affect .NET Core itself.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Their question is about using the Firebird .net Provider, so they likely can find help there.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos .NET 6 is only usable with VS 2022 which our company not yet has given free for us and I don't want to use the Community Edition in a professional context.

Comment: I have figured out the problem though and will provide the answer in a reply to this question

Comment: @KatharinaUtecht the company's preferences won't make .NET 5 supported. This isn't a "we can still use that old version" situation. In any case you can use Rider or VS Code and Community is essentially Professional without the Azure perks *and* allowed for professional use for companies up to a certain size. .NET 5 is not supported in production for *anything*

Comment: Besides, how are you going to tell your *customers* to use an unsupported .NET version? Unsupported as in not-even-getting-security-fixes? What happens if the customers refuse to install an unsupported runtime?

Answer (score 1):

So the answer was that you cannot declare the DbProviderFactory in the app.config anymore. I found this in some StackOverflow question which I cannot find the link to anymore.

However, you can register it programmatically during the startup of your application:

```cs
DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory("firebird", FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory.Instance);
```

In the app.config use:

```xml
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="EntityFramework.Firebird.FbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework.Firebird" />
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="firebird" type="EntityFramework.Firebird.FbProviderServices, EntityFramework.Firebird"/>
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

with matching invariantName for the provider and key for the registration during Startup.

This setup worked for me.

Comment: I already explained that .NET Core doesn't use app.config, it uses a compleltely different configuration system. EF Core doesn't need DbProviderFactory either. When you create or register a DbContext using DbContextOptions you specify the provider with `UseSqlServer` or `UseMySql`.

Comment: You should probably check [Entity Framework Core -Connection Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings)

Comment: This is not how Entity Framework Core works. App.Config and DbProvider factories are a .Net Framework. Check this lib that might work, and also there's a brief explanation how to use: https://github.com/ralmsdeveloper/EntityFrameworkCore.FirebirdSQL